# CUDA, shared memory limit on CC 2.0 card

Tags: cuda, gpu-shared-memory

I know "Maximum amount of shared memory per multiprocessor" for GPU with Compute Capability 2.0 is 48KB as is said in the guide.

I'm a little confused about the amount of shared memory I can use for each block? How many blocks are in a multiprocessor. I'm using a GeForce GTX 580.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Fermi, you can use up to 16kb or 48kb (depending on the configuration you select) of shared memory per block - the number of blocks which will run concurrently on a multiprocessor is determined by how much shared memory and registers each block requires, up to a maximum of 8. If you use 48kb, then only a single block can run concurrently. If you use 1kb per block, then up to 8 blocks could run concurrently per multiprocessor, depending on their register usage.

Comment: so I assume it's fastest if I could use less than 48/8 per block ? and btw. how can I determine the number of registers I'm using?

Comment: Use the nvcc compiler option -Xptxas -v to have the compiler report the register and memory usage of each kernel.

Comment: You can also run your kernel in the compute visual profiler -- it'll in the occupancy analysis tab it'll show you how much shared memory and registers a kernel uses, and from that, how many blocks ran concurrently on each multiprocessor.